# how to make blender automatically use relative paths 2.8

Tags: customization

How can i make blender always use relative paths?

I looked into the preferences but couldn't find any setting for this. apparently in 2.79 there was such a setting but in the newest version it seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is located in *Edit> Preferences* under the *Save & Load* category, then *Blend Files> Relative Paths*:

[image]